# formatting controls are missing for posts

Tags: bug, status-planned, formatting

In both Firefox 3.6 and IE 7 (yeah, I know -- corporate IT restrictions) on Windows XP, I am no longer seeing the buttons for formatting, link, etc above the textbox where you type posts.  In Firefox I turned off Ghostscript and Stylish (just in case), and I've never customized IE for anything other than default font size.

These buttons were present when I posted a question last night from home (Firefox 10 or 11 on OS 10.6).

I don't know if it's related, but I'm currently also not seeing a preview of this post.

Comment: And for the first time I had to answer a captcha to post this, even though I'm logged in. ???

Comment: looks like it will be [resolved soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132151/147574).

Comment: I've tagged this [meta-tag:status-planned] for now. Can anyone confirm whether it's in fact extant or gone? MonicaCellio, @Jin?

Comment: This has been resolved for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's my employer's fault and is affecting most SE sites, not just this one.  I found [this discussion on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132133/162102).